# Push WP posts to Gab.ai... through RSS Feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss, social-media

I have a potential client who would like to be able to feed Twitter posts to Wordpress (easy), and then have the WP posts automatically create posts on Gab.ai. I haven't seen a way that Gab can facilitate that, but they would like to be able to make Twitter threads, which doesn't seem like an option if you go the other direction.

Is there a way to create an automatic system like this through an RSS Feed or something?